# Color specific node in Gantt Mermaid diagram

Tags: gantt-chart, mermaid

I would like to color a specific node in a Gantt chart using `mermaid`. It is easy to color a specific node in a flowchart, but it is not clear to me how to do this in a Gantt chart. I would like to color the node "Color this node to green" to green. Here is some reproducible code:

```
gantt
    title A Gantt Diagram
    dateFormat YYYY-MM-DD
    section Section
        A task          :a1, 2014-01-01, 30d
        Another task    :after a1, 20d
    section Another
        Task in Another :2014-01-12, 12d
        Color this node to green    :24d
```

Output:

[image]

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to color a specific node in a Gantt chart mermaid?